# Is there a way to check for unused indexes in google datastore?

Tags: indexing, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to know if there is a way to get the list of unused index in datastore? If not, is there an easy work around way to delete the ones that are not in use?

Answer (score 1):

> is there an easy work around way to delete the ones that are not in use?

`gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml` will delete all indexes that are no longer present in your `index.yaml` file

Comment: Good to know that at least we can go through indexes and clean up them manually, as there is no option in Datastore UI on GCP for that

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of [**indexes**](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) in Cloud Datastore: **built-in** and **composed**.

If you're using **composed indexes**, you can get the count of indexes per kind with the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/datastore/indexes/):

```
gcloud --project=PROJECT_ID beta datastore indexes list | grep 'kind: ' | sort | uniq -c
```

However, this command doesn't work with the built-in indexes but there is a **feature request** for that, which you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/143745331).

Other than that, you would need to implement some logging on your end in order to track the usage of indexes.